# VSC “Format Document” messes up #include order

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino

My problem is pretty much what the title says:
When I use STRG-ALT-F to format my C++ files VSC also messes with the order of #includes.
And of cause this leads to errors that were not there before… :-(

For example *this*

```
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/gpio_sig_map.h"
#include "soc/i2s_reg.h"
#include "soc/i2s_struct.h"
#include "soc/io_mux_reg.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/periph_ctrl.h"
#include "rom/lldesc.h"
#include "XClk.h"
#include "DMABuffer.h"
```

becomes this

```
#include "DMABuffer.h"
#include "XClk.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/periph_ctrl.h"
#include "rom/lldesc.h"
#include "soc/gpio_sig_map.h"
#include "soc/i2s_reg.h"
#include "soc/i2s_struct.h"
#include "soc/io_mux_reg.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"
```

… and subsequently fails compile.

Is there a way to forbid the formatter reordering and stick to formatting stuff?

*Using PlatformIO in VSC on OSX.*

Comment: Why is the include order important? That seems to me the core of the problem...

Comment: I have no idea, but I guess that's a C++ / platformIO secret.
What I can say for this case: the included "DMAbuffer.h" throws an exception, because it requires typedefinitions from "rom/lldesc.h"
Noticed it before, it's also annoying when you group your includes for readability.

Comment: OK, I can workaround by putting a comment above the last #include so it won't mix with the rest.
So I guess (really not an expert) that adding #include "rom/lldesc.h" (part of a platform definition/sdk) into DMAbuffer.h (selfmade part) is the way to do this? Just tried it and it works.

Comment: Exactly that is the way it should be done! Every header file should include all those header files it depends on.